# legacy-install-failure when trying to install pyzmq package through homebrew and pip

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, failed-installation, pyzmq

I'm trying to install the PROS CLI on macOS (https://pros.cs.purdue.edu/v5/getting-started/macos.html) through Homebrew, but I keep experiencing errors that I'm unable to fix or find solutions to online (I already attempted to install the CLI through the VS Code extension which also did not work).

I've completed all the previous steps, but when running `brew install pros-cli` I get the error:

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/***/Library/Logs/Homebrew/pros-cli/13.pip:
  
  exec(compile(setup_py_code, filename, "exec"))
  '"'"''"'"''"'"' % ('"'"'/private/tmp/pros-cli--pyzmq-20230401-14633-yuj94s/pyzmq-20.0.0/setup.py'"'"',), "<pip-setuptools-caller>", "exec"))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-74volvcf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pros-cli/3.4.1/libexec/include/site/python3.11/pyzmq
  cwd: /private/tmp/pros-cli--pyzmq-20230401-14633-yuj94s/pyzmq-20.0.0/
  Running setup.py install for pyzmq: finished with status 'error'
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pyzmq

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0.1
[notice] To update, run: python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade pip

If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/homebrew-core):
  https://github.com/purduesigbots/homebrew-pros/issues
```

I've done some research on this problem online, but all I've found are tips on how to solve legacy-install-failure in general, none of which have worked for me.